# Magento - how to declare multiple helper classes in the same config

Tags: magento

Could someone please tell me how I can declare multiple helpers within the same config file for the same module?

I've been using helper utility files for awhile now, but as my utility method is becoming increasingly long, with many functions, I'd like to split it up into seperate helper utility classes based on the functionality. So I'd have a class called Categoryhelper and one called Attributehelper. Obviously this step I can do, but I'm not sure how to declare these in the config.xml.

I've tried messing around with the config, doing trial and error but cant seem to get anything to work.

Here's what I originally had, using the default helper:

(note - my custom module name is called 'Helper'

```
<global>
...
<helpers>
    <helper>
        <class>GPMClient_Helper_Helper</class>
        </helper>
</helpers>
...
```

and here's what I've tried:

```
<helpers>
<helper>
            <class>GPMClient_Helper_Helper/Categoryhelper</class>
    </helper>
    <helper>
            <class>GPMClient_Helper_Helper/Attributehelper</class>
    </helper>
```

and:

```
<helpers>
<helper>
            <class>GPMClient_Helper_Helper/Categoryhelper</class>
        <class>GPMClient_Helper_Helper/Attributehelper</class>
    </helper>
```

Should the helper classes go into their own  xml fragment or should both be grouped together?

If anyone could please post a sample config with multiple helper classes declared, I'd be most grateful.

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you got wrong how it works. When you add next lines to your GPMClient_Helper module config.xml

```
<helpers>
    <helper>
        <class>GPMClient_Helper_Helper</class>
    </helper>
</helpers>
```

you define class prefix for all your helpers. So, now in your `GPMClient/Helper/Helper` directory you should create file `Data.php` with `GPMClient_Helper_Helper_Data`code inside and any number of classes named `GPMClient_Helper_Helper_*`.

Comment: Thanks Zyava, I thought I must have been doing something wrong!